# How to send notification to windows desktop application from cloud server?

Tags: java, windows, cloud

I need to know the way by which I can send push notifications to windows application from a cloud server. I searched and found the WNS for windows 8. But what about others like windows 7 and windows XP.

Any reply would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no push notification service built into Windows 7 or Windows XP; it was a feature added in Windows 8 for WinRT apps (which are not allowed to run constantly). However, in Win32 you should have the ability to maintain a persistent connection to your service or poll regularly to see if there is new info from the service.